# better approach to define java constants for numeral values

Tags: java

In java, we can define constants to avoid magic numbers e.g. list size , days.
My question is regarding reusing of the constant defined for numerals in code.

Approach 1: 
I can define two constant which both have value 30 .

```
public static final int ONE_MONTH=30
public static final int LIST_SIZE_THIRTY=30
```

Approach 2: 
I can define one constant with value 30.

```
public static final int THIRTY=30
```

Both are correct from java syntax perspective. Although approach 1 is giving more info but have to define two constants. Approach 2 is just a number written in english and can be used both places where we were suppose to use ONE_MONTH and LIST_SIZE_THIRTY.

Which approach is recommended and why ?

Comment: See [all the questions already on Programmers Stack Exchange about magic numbers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/search?q=magic+numbers+is%3Aquestion)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you want is the question.

**You want readibility and reusability? Take the first one.**

You want memory optimization? Take the second solution.

Why? Imagine tomorrow there will be 35 days in a month for any reason. with the second, you'll have to rework all your app, with the first, you'll juste have to change 30 to 35.

EDIT : To be clear, **first solution is from far the best**, no doubt about it, unless you're in a very very (very very very...) memory restrictive development...

Comment: The second one is a so-called optimization that's meaningless.  Please prefer the first one.  It's all about readability.

Comment: I would hardly call declaring one or two less variables optimization. It's as bad as using 30 directly because if you later change the value to 31, your code still reads thirty everywhere and you would want to change that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you define a constant such as

```
public static final int LIST_SIZE_THIRTY=30
```

it's quite the same as using 30 because if the default size becomes 20 it's not recommended to end with something like

```
public static final int LIST_SIZE_THIRTY=20
```

or creating a new constant and replacing the old one.
**Your constants shoud be meaningful, i.e they must help who reads and maintains the code (even if he/she is the code author)**.

so my suggestion is something like:

```
public static final int ONE_MONTH=30;
public static final int DEFAULT_LIST_SIZE=30;
```

because they have different meanings, i.e. different semantic. If in you first version the requirements states that default list size is one_month you could stress it with

```
public static final int ONE_MONTH=30;
public static final int DEFAULT_LIST_SIZE=ONE_MONTH;
```

P.S. I did not consider that defining two constants uses more memory because this is a design question and one or two (or even more) variables *usually* do not make such a difference in terms of used memory in a Java program.

Answer (score 0):

There is one alternative, change your second Approach like below--
Maintain one Constants class--

```
public class Constants{

public static final int NUMBER_THIRTY=30;
....
...  //rest of the class
```

}

And then, use Enums like below--

```
imprort ...Constants;
 public enum EnumConstants {

        MONTH(Constants.NUMBER_THIRTY),
             LIST_SIZE_THIRTY(Constants.NUMBER_THIRTY);

        int value;

    private EnumConstants(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int value() {
        return value;

    }

}
```

So by this way, you can achive  code reusability, code readability, and maitainability. ( in future, if value of month changes, as stated in one answer, then you only need to change value in Constants class.)